# What's the meaning of "pg_noinline" in these code segments?

Tags: c, postgresql, inline

Below are the code segments from postgreSQL(version `REL_13_STABLE`), I remove some codes to  simplify the logic here. The basic logic is to search in catalog cache, if you cant find the entry in catalog cache, then look up for it in the catalog table using `SearchCatCacheMiss`.

```
static inline HeapTuple
SearchCatCacheInternal(CatCache *cache,
                       int nkeys,
                       Datum v1,
                       Datum v2,
                       Datum v3,
                       Datum v4)
{
    hashValue = CatalogCacheComputeHashValue(cache, nkeys, v1, v2, v3, v4);
    hashIndex = HASH_INDEX(hashValue, cache->cc_nbuckets);

    bucket = &cache->cc_bucket[hashIndex];
    dlist_foreach(iter, bucket)
    {
        /* loop to find the cache entry, if found then return */
    }

    return SearchCatCacheMiss(cache, nkeys, hashValue, hashIndex, v1, v2, v3, v4);
}
```

And I'm quite curious about the `pg_noinline` in the `SearchCatCacheMiss` function signature. So my understanding is pg is using `pg_noinline` to make sure fast-path is small enough so that it can fit into instruction cache? But it seems strange, CPU has no idea of function calling, so using `pg_noinline` should not affect how CPU handles instruction cache, even if `SearchCatCacheMiss` got inlined, it will still be infrequent for CPU to execute instructions of `SearchCatCacheMiss`, and instructions of `SearchCatCacheMiss` will not be loaded into instruction cache.

```
/*
 * Search the actual catalogs, rather than the cache.
 *
 * This is kept separate from SearchCatCacheInternal() to keep the fast-path
 * as small as possible.  To avoid that effort being undone by a helpful
 * compiler, try to explicitly forbid inlining.
 */
static pg_noinline HeapTuple
SearchCatCacheMiss(CatCache *cache,
                   int nkeys,
                   uint32 hashValue,
                   Index hashIndex,
                   Datum v1,
                   Datum v2,
                   Datum v3,
                   Datum v4)
```

Comment: https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2338922

Answer (score 2):

`pg_noinline` is a macro that expands to a compiler-specific directive that discourages the conpiler from inlining that function. The idea is that the compiler should inline `SearchCatCacheInternal`, which should be as fast as possible and avoid the overhead of a function call, but it should not inline `SearchCatCacheMiss`, since that is not performance critical, and there is no point in wasting space in the binary by duplicating that code